# Python: Unpack list of dicts containing individual np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a pure numpy way that I can use to get to this expected outcome?
Right now I have to use Pandas and I would like to skip it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

listOfDicts = [{'key1': np.array(10), 'key2': np.array(10), 'key3': np.array(44)},
               {'key1': np.array(2), 'key2': np.array(15), 'key3': np.array(22)},
               {'key1': np.array(25), 'key2': np.array(25), 'key3': np.array(11)},
               {'key1': np.array(35), 'key2': np.array(55), 'key3': np.array(22)}]
```

Use pandas to parse:

```
# pandas can unpack simply
df = pd.DataFrame(listOfDicts)

# get all values under the same key
xd = df.to_dict('list')

# ultimate goal
np.stack([v for k, v in xd.items() if k not in ['key1']], axis=1)

array([[10, 44],
       [15, 22],
       [25, 11],
       [55, 22]])
```

```
# I would like listOfDicts to transform temporarily into this with pure numpy,
# from which I could do basically anything to it:
{'key1': [np.array([10, 2, 25, 35])],
 'key2': [np.array([10, 15, 25, 55])],
 'key3': [np.array([44, 22, 11, 22])]
 }
```

Comment: You seem to be depending on the order of the dict for the values. Can you also depend on `key1` being the first value?

Comment: Yes! That is expected!

Comment: The maybe you just want `np.array([list(d.values())[1:] for d in listOfDicts])`

Comment: Ah, I still want to be able to reference the keys. Let me edit!

Comment: If you still "want to be able to reference the keys", then Pandas is your friend, not your enemy.

Comment: Stick with your first `pd.DataFrame` constructor and stop there. Do not juggle lists and dicts. You can more easily "do basically anything" to a regular dataframe with a good index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to turn your dataframe into a dictionary of numpy arrays, is to transpose it and use [`DataFrame.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to merge the columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

listOfDicts = [{'key1': np.array(10), 'key2': np.array(10), 'key3': np.array(44)},
               {'key1': np.array(2),  'key2': np.array(15), 'key3': np.array(22)},
               {'key1': np.array(25), 'key2': np.array(25), 'key3': np.array(11)},
               {'key1': np.array(35), 'key2': np.array(55), 'key3': np.array(22)}]

df.transpose().agg(np.stack, axis=1).to_dict()

# {'key1': array([10,  2, 25, 35]),
#  'key2': array([10, 15, 25, 55]),
#  'key3': array([44, 22, 11, 22])}
```

If you just want the values, you can pull those out and stack them and then slice and dice with numpy:

```
np.stack(df.transpose().agg(np.stack, axis=1).values)

# array([[10,  2, 25, 35],
#        [10, 15, 25, 55],
#        [44, 22, 11, 22]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Without pandas:

```
In [162]: listOfDicts
Out[162]: 
[{'key1': array(10), 'key2': array(10), 'key3': array(44)},
 {'key1': array(2), 'key2': array(15), 'key3': array(22)},
 {'key1': array(25), 'key2': array(25), 'key3': array(11)},
 {'key1': array(35), 'key2': array(55), 'key3': array(22)}]
```

Use `items` if you want list/tuple instead of dict:

```
In [163]: [list(d.items()) for d in listOfDicts]
Out[163]: 
[[('key1', array(10)), ('key2', array(10)), ('key3', array(44))],
 [('key1', array(2)), ('key2', array(15)), ('key3', array(22))],
 [('key1', array(25)), ('key2', array(25)), ('key3', array(11))],
 [('key1', array(35)), ('key2', array(55)), ('key3', array(22))]]
```

If the keys are all the same, `values` gives a simpler list:

```
In [164]: [list(d.values()) for d in listOfDicts]
Out[164]: 
[[array(10), array(10), array(44)],
 [array(2), array(15), array(22)],
 [array(25), array(25), array(11)],
 [array(35), array(55), array(22)]]
```

Those rows can be combined into one array with:

```
In [165]: [np.hstack(list(d.values())) for d in listOfDicts]
Out[165]: 
[array([10, 10, 44]),
 array([ 2, 15, 22]),
 array([25, 25, 11]),
 array([35, 55, 22])]
```

and a further stack to get a 2d array:

```
In [166]: np.vstack(_)
Out[166]: 
array([[10, 10, 44],
       [ 2, 15, 22],
       [25, 25, 11],
       [35, 55, 22]])
```

and the transpose if you prefer:

```
In [167]: _.T
Out[167]: 
array([[10,  2, 25, 35],
       [10, 15, 25, 55],
       [44, 22, 11, 22]])
```

`numpy` doesn't have any special dict knowledge, so alot this is plain python.